Alexa Skill - User Input via typing through the Alexa App
I need to store some data from the user that would not be picked up accurately via voice so it requires the user to type the item.
Is there a way I can prompt the user to go to the Alexa App. The Alexa App has a notification or activity that they can click on and from there they can type the item. The Alexa skill can then store it.
I believe there is a way that you can type and submit text on devices with screens but need a solution for when they might not have a screen as well.
Or are we getting into the realms of account linking into a web app here.

You can do it via routes like a "fake" account linking page which captures user input and stores it into a DB or similar which the skill can then access.  There is no Amazon provided easy route for you to capture user input.
